# Get all images that mouse is not over in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mousemove, image-effects

I have a WPF Window that gets filled with multple images, I am trying to find a way to blur all the images the mouse is NOT hovering over.

I am using this event to effect images that I am hovering over:

```
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is Image)
    {
        ((Image)e.OriginalSource).Effect = new BlurEffect();
    }
}
```

This is how I created the images

```
        StackPanel imgStkpnl = new StackPanel();

        foreach (var urll in Tools.MyGlobals.GoogleImageURLs)
        {
            var image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            var fullFilePath = urll;

            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            try
            {
                bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(fullFilePath, UriKind.Absolute);
                bitmap.EndInit();

                image.Source = bitmap;
                image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
                image.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

                imgStkpnl.Children.Add(image);
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

If anyone knows a way to effect all the other images that would be a great help, I'm a big newby so go easy on me :) Thanks

Comment: There should also be `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events

Comment: My laptops running out of battery so don't have time to write a proper answer, but the obvious solution is to blur all images by default, and then ''unblur' the image the mouse is over, rather than the other way around

Comment: Sorry I should of added, I am trying to make it so the image I am over unblurs, but when i move over multiple images they will all stay unblurred I want them to return back to how they were.Thanks for your answers by the way, I appreciate it.

Comment: You could use an [implicit Style](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/implicit-style/) for all your `Image` in that XAML that would set the `Effect` property.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve your desired effect using this XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Solutions.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>

        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <BlurEffect x:Key="BlurEffect"></BlurEffect>

            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource BlurEffect}"></Setter>

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" >
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Null}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BlurEffect}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Image Source="cat.jpg" Width="200"></Image>
        <Image Source="cat.jpg" Width="200"></Image>
        <Image Source="cat.jpg" Width="200"></Image>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[image: Example]

Following on from your comment, to leave the image unblurred, just remove the `MouseLeave` event trigger

Comment: Is there any way to create a style trigger programatically, I created my images in c#. I edited my post so you can see how I did it.

Comment: Using your code in the original question, when the image is created, you can set the blur effect, then in the window mouse move event handler, you could set it to null instead

Comment: Personally, I like to keep everything visual in XAML. You could even just apply that style to the whole window instead, so that all images that get added to the window will inherit that style, even if the images are added programatically

Comment: I did not know I could apply it to the whole window, that will work perfectly for me once I figure out how to do that :P thanks for everything!

Comment: You know where it says <stackpanel.resources>? Change that to window.resources and put it under the window element. I'm at the park with the kids right now but I'll update my answer when I get back if you haven't figured it out!

Comment: I figured it out it works great, you're awesome man, thanks :)